# PHP Regular expression to match unescaped double quotes

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to figure out a regular expression that will detect if there is an unescaped double quote within two double quotes. I have this, but it's not working:

```
if ( preg_match( '/^(\".*((?<!\\)\").*\")$/', $str ) ) {
    die("hey");
}
```

Comment: I don't think it's possible to do that with a Regex. At least if you want it a bit more general - if you only need to match a single pair of double quotes, and a single unescaped one then it's possible.

Comment: Not a regex expert so not putting this in an answer but what about `^(\\)\".*^(\\)\"` You check if there's not a \ but there is a " with anything before another " without a \ in front of it.

Comment: @Ariel It's for error checking. If there are any unescaped double quotes within the two doubles quotes then we have an error. That's all I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `preg_match('/([^\\]\")/', $str)`

Comment: This is incorrect. `\\"` is an unescaped quote preceded by a literal backslash, but it won't be matched by this regex.